# Let $U = \{ p \in {P_4}(F):p(2) = p(5)\}$ find basis of U

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

Let $U = \{ p \in {P_4}(F):p(2) = p(5)\}$ find basis of
Then extend the basis to a basis of P4.

I don't have any idea where should I start, can anyone please give me a hint?

Comment: Do you know how to find the null space of a matrix? Do you know how to find a basis for this nullspace?

Comment: I'm not that much familiar with matrix yet could you explain more?

Comment: That surprising, so for me it's not clear exactly what you know or don't know yet. With that said, it would be helpful if you could explain a bit more about the context of your question, as is [explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). For example, where did you come across this problem?  Is there a problem similar to this one that you do know how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u \in U$ then $u(x)=n_4x^4+n_3x^3+n_2x^2+n_1x_1+n_0$ we also know that

$u(2)=u(5)$ $\Rightarrow$ $16n_4+8n_3+4n_2+2n_1+n_0=625n_4+125n_3+25n_2+5n_1+n_0$

$609n_4+117n_3+21n_2+3n_1=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $n_1=-203n_4-39n_3-7n_2$

so we can say that

$U=\{p(x)=n_4x^4+n_3x^3+n_2x^2+n_1x_1+n_0:(n_0,-203n_4-39n_3-7n_2,n_2,n_3,n_4)\}$

there are 4 generators as you can see all we have to do is prove that they are linearly independent

$1,-7x+x^2,x^3-39x,x^4-203x$

$c_0+c_1(-7x+x^2)+c_2(x^3-39x)+c_3(x^4-203x)=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $c_0=c_1=c_2=c_3=0$

which means they are linearly independent.If you add x to this set you will have an extended basis

Comment: thank you so much